# MASM errors on Build in VS10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly, syntax, compilation, masm

The attached code is a supplied source for a SaveGame cleaner.
The only thing that is not clear is the entry point, which has been set as main.
But the decompiler at [http://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/] gave something like _start.
The first codeblock is

```
; SaveTool V 1.13
_______________________________________________________________________________________

[true 1    false 0    NULL 0]


[FilterStrings: B$  'Save Files', 0, '*.ess', 0
                0,0,0]
*Error  6   error A2044: invalid character in file  SaveCleaner.asm 12  1*  SaveCleanerNextline
   [UserFileFilter: 0 #50] [ChoosenFile: 0 #64]


[OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST 01000  OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST 0800     OFN_LONGNAMES 0200000
 OFN_EXPLORER 080000      OFN_HIDEREADONLY 04]


[OFN_FLAGS        OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST+OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST+OFN_LONGNAMES+OFN_HIDEREADONLY+OFN_EXPLORER]


[OpenFileNameStructure:  len  hwndFileOwner: 0  OF_hInstance: 0  FilterStrings
                         0  0 1 FullChoosenFile 200 ChoosenFile
                         80  NULL  OpenFileTitle  OFN_FLAGS
                         nFileOffsetinChoosenFile: W$ 0  nFileExtensioninChoosenFile: 0
                         DefaultExtension: D$ NULL
                         HookCustomData:  NULL  HookProcPtr: NULL  HookTemplateName: 0 0   0 0 ]

[OpenFileTitle:        'Open .ess file' 0]
*Error  6   error A2044: invalid character in file  SaveCleaner.asm 12  1      SaveCleanerNextline*
[FullChoosenFile: 0 #64] [<16 algn: 0]
   __________________________________________________________________________________________
```

The complete codeblock is too large for posting here so it can be downloaded (right click) at [http://www.ozemail.com.au/~lmstearn/files/SaveTool-source.asm]
The config has been set correctly to compile the code but comes up with a mass of errors.

> SaveCleaner.asm(142): error A2008: syntax error : 
>   SaveCleaner.asm(156): error A2044: invalid character in file
>   SaveCleaner.asm(158): fatal error A1012: error count exceeds 100; stopping assembly
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(49,5): >error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\SaveCleaner.obj" /I >"C:\masm32\lib" /I "C:\masm32\include" /I "C:\masm32\macros" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  >/TaSaveCleaner.asm" exited with code 1.

What is missed in the VS setup?

Comment: That doesn't look like MASM syntax. What assembler is it written for?

Comment: I've really no idea. Instruction set looks similar to [http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.kui0006a/a251_cs_reference.htm]

Comment: Tip from the old days: a mass of errors almost always means that you have one syntax error, probably near either [A] the very start,  or [B] the very end.  To annoy you even further, the syntax error which is causing this error is probably unrelated.  My immediate two suggestions are (1) look at the first error reported on its line, and go backwards from there, looking for culprits, then (2) if you don't find it there, look at the last one, and start looking for the culprit in lines that follow that one.

Comment: Looked at FilterStrings- no such thing in MASM. There's FilterString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that your asm source is a **[RosASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RosAsm)** source code and you will have no chance to compile it under MASM / Visual Studio.

RosASM is a win32 assembler that used a quite original design that let it store the source code *inside* the compiled executable (in a dedicated section) and many other features like an integrated IDE, integrated debugger, some powerful macros, a resource editor, a dialog editor, an original source navigation style that does not need scrolling bar, the possibility to divide the source in chapters called "titles"... Quite a surprising tool that need some practice to get comfortable with it, that I still use for asm win32 programming.

[image: RosASM]

I have checked that the code assembles with RosASM, but I get neither an error nor a result as I do not have the corresponding game.

The original RosASM web site is now vanished, but there is a [dedicated forum](http://rosasm.freeforums.org/) recently back online and I maintain an [archive site](http://sebastien.kirche.free.fr/rosasm_mirror/) where you can get binaries, and a lot of examples and fully functional applications (even a working NES emulator) made with RosASM that could help you to learn RosASM usage. FYI, SpASM is RosASM ancestor and BUASM was a revamping of RosASM that is unfinished.

Concerning the executable entry point, you can get it by looking at the `Proc Main` int the `TITLE MAIN`, that reads:

```
Proc Main:

    call 'KERNEL32.HeapCreate' 0 0 0 | mov D$Heap eax

    call 'Kernel32.GetModuleHandleA' 0  | mov D$hInstance eax
    call 'USER32.DialogBoxParamA'  eax IDD_MAINDIALOG &NULL DialogProc &NULL

    call 'KERNEL32.HeapDestroy' D$Heap
    call 'KERNEL32.ExitProcess' 0
EndP
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the info Seki. I kind of figured out the entry point, but it didn't amount to a hill o' beans running through the wrong compiler! Actually the guy who wrote the code is still working on it, so I think I'll back away slowly :) But nevertheless this RosASM is more than impressive. Does the move to 64bit really knell doom for these kinds of projects (albeit still active viz. Wikipedia)?

Comment: @LaurieStearn: You just make me notice that the wikipedia page was back online since 2012 (IIRC it was once deleted). One of the RosAsm contributors (Rémi Coquet) was working on a RosAsm revamping and 64-bit adaptation called BUAsm (Bottom-up asm). I have some early versions in my archives but not fresh ones.